# Passing arguments to button onclick method in vuejs

Tags: button, vue.js, onclick, parameter-passing, vue-component

I am trying to pass the selected values from the tag and pass it to a button’s click event. However, I was not able to get the data in the onclick function. See the code below.

I am getting `undefined` in the alert.
Please help.

```
<div class=“form-group”>
   <div class=“form-group” align=“center”>
      <label for=“select-Year”>Select CMS Fiscal Year :</label>
      <select class=“form-control input-sm” style=“width:120px” id=“select-Year”>     
         <option v-for=“yr in years” value=“yr”>{{ yr }}</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <br/><br/>

   <div class=“form-group” style=“align:center”>
      <button id=“btnSubmit” class=“btn btn-primary” style=“align:center” v-on:click=“loadData(yr, $event)”>Open</button>
   </div>
</div>

methods: {
  `loadData`: function(yr, event){
    alert(yr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do this for you, go to the page and see    `<https://jsfiddle.net/Lr3psu2y/>`.
    Hope it with help for you.

Comment: Thanks man. your code works perfectly. but it also throws a warning in the console as below "<option v-model="yrInd">: v-model is not supported on this element type. If you are working with contenteditable, it's recommended to wrap a library dedicated for that purpose inside a custom component.".          will it make any problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The `yr` variable only exists within the scope of `option` when you used `v-for` on it.

That's why it's causing an error when you try to pass it to the event handler of your `button` which is located outside the scope of `v-for`.

**How can I get selected option?**

One way to get the `year` selected is to declare a `year` variable under your component `data` attribute and use the [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) directive on your `select` field to form a two-way binding.

```
data: function() {
  return {
    year: null
  }
}
```

And in your select and button tags,

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" style="width:120px" id="select-Year" v-model="year">
  <option v-for="yr in years" value="yr">{{ yr }}</option>
</select>
```

```
<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" style="align:center" v-on:click="loadData($event)">Open</button>
```

In this way, you can get access to the `year` in `loadData`,

```
loadData(event) {
  console.log(this.year, event);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ana, thanks for your response. i am creating that whole html code as a template using the <script type="text/x-template" id=""></script> option. for this vue.component() i have already have a data from where i am getting the array values for the for loop. Do i have to give the v-model for a property in that same vue.component or the vue instance ??

Comment: Hey @Mani079, can you create a fiddle for this? It would make it faster and easier to resolve which shows how it's being used in another component.